Using Volley instead of Gson and OkHttpClient to request service:
I'm relatively new to API integration and would appreciate some guidance on transitioning my code from using OkHttpClient and Gson to using Volley and JSONObject for API requests.
Initially, I developed a service request feature using OkHttpClient and Gson, and everything seemed to work fine. However, upon completing the implementation, I discovered that another part of the application relies on Volley as a library and JSONObject for making requests.
When I attempted to modify my code to use Volley instead of Gson and OkHttpClient, I encountered an error message: "E [93] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 307 for https://url/score".
Could someone please help me understand what this error message means and how I can resolve it?
Thank you in advance for your assistance. If you need further clarification or code snippets, please let me know.
  private suspend fun scoreAudioWithASR(audioUri: Uri, text: String): String {

        val audioBuffer = uriToBase64(context, audioUri)

        val requestDict = mapOf(
            "lang_code" to "voice",
            "gender" to "M",
            "text" to text,
            "audio" to audioBuffer,
            "tag" to "test"
        )

//        inspect the data produced for debugging purposes
//        saveRequestData(requestDict)



        val gson = Gson()

        val requestBody = gson.toJson(requestDict)
            .toRequestBody("json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())

        val requestBodyJsonString = gson.toJson(requestDict)
        Log.d("JSON Object", requestBodyJsonString)

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://url/score")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
                    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
                    val responseDict = gson.fromJson(response.body?.string(), Map::class.java)
                    val utteranceDp = responseDict["utterance_dp"] as Double

                    Log.d("utteranceDp",utteranceDp.toString() )

                    val utteranceThresholds = responseDict["utterance_thresholds"] as List<Double>

                    Log.d("utteranceThresholds",utteranceThresholds.toString() )

                    if (utteranceDp > utteranceThresholds[1]) "good" else "try again"
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("ASRScore", "Error making ASR request", e)
                "error message."
            }
        }
    }```


the code I am trying to use with Volley is:




private suspend fun scoreAudioWithASR(
audioUri: Uri,
text: String,
): String {
return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
val audioBuffer = uriToBase64(context, audioUri)
val url = "https://url/score/"
        val jsonObject = JSONObject().apply {
            put("lang_code", "zul_kids")
            put("gender", "M")
            put("text", text)
            put("audio", audioBuffer)
            put("tag", "test")
        }

// Convert JSON object to a formatted string
val jsonString = jsonObject.toString(4)
// Log the formatted JSON string
Log.d("JSON Object", jsonString)
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, jsonObject,
            { response ->
                // Handle successful response
                val responseDict = response as Map<*, *>
                val utteranceDp = responseDict["utterance_dp"] as Double
                val utteranceThresholds = responseDict["utterance_thresholds"] as List<Double>

                val result = if (utteranceDp > utteranceThresholds[1]) {
                    "WWell done!"
                } else {
                    "Not good, try again"
                }
                continuation.resume(result)
            },
            { error ->
                // Handle Volley error
                Log.e("API Error", "Error fetching game configuration: ${error.message}")
                continuation.resumeWithException(error)
            }
        )
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}```

Then I get error : " E  [93] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 307 for https://url/score"
I tried to add the redirection got almost same error or the request run infinitely.

"would appreciate some guidance on transitioning my code from using OkHttpClient and Gson to using Volley and JSONObject for API requests" -- that seems like the wrong direction to move. Volley has been abandoned for years. While Gson is not getting updates, it is a better API for JSON than is JSONObject. I would use kotlinx.serialization or Moshi for JSON parsing nowadays.

I always die a little inside when I see kotlin+gson tags combined.

so do you want to learn the best way for api integration right?

Thank you all (@CommonsWare and @Pawel) for your suggestions. My worry was that I wanted to make the app uniform. But I will consider your suggestions.
@Laser : Yes, of course I will appreciate that.
